# Exception while registering Interceptor class TestInterceptor - interceptor - file:WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:15:75

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, struts2

I am trying to read context parameter from web.xml in my custom interceptor struts2. 
Please find my code snippet and web.xml below.

```
 public class TestInterceptor implements Interceptor, ServletContextAware {
    private ServletContext servletContext;  

    string abc = servletContext.getInitParameter(someSetting);  

    @Override
      public void setServletContext(final ServletContext context) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
      }
    }
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>someSetting</param-name>
  <param-value>someValue</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: you don't have an exception list here... and the type should be 'String' not 'string'. also, you probably want to set this parameter 'after' you're assured that the servlet context is not null

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

This code cannot work, because you are accessing servletContext before it is set. Try extracting your string inside the setServletContext-method.

Comment: that's correct i am getting servletContext object as null thats why i am getting this exception (null pointer exception while calling method on null object ).. but i have to call that string from init method only as i am getting datasource object from init method. can you please sugest me alternate way to do get this context object by using struts2.

Comment: Init() Method of my custom Interceptor.